# How do i access a list from a JSON file with Python?

Tags: python, json

I have a program that is loading a JSON file in Python. How do i access a list from this file. Here is my code that loads it:

```
with open("database.py") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
```

How do I access 'mylist'? Something like this?:

```
obj = json.loads(mylist)
print(obj)
```

It's throwing `NameError: name 'mylist' is not defined`.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is an example JSON contents: `["mylist = (\"CSDL\",\"ETF\",\"STF\")"]` . This is everything in the database.py file. How would I call on the list, `mylist`?

Comment: Could you post an example of your JSON file?

Comment: Done. I seem to be able to access it by `mylist = json_data[0]`. But i would like to be able to access it by name ('mylist') not by list index.

Comment: Why does your JSON file has ".py" extension? Why do you expect being able to access anything by 'mylist' key if there is no "mylist" in your file?

Comment: @isobolev I made it .py because I want others to be able to look at and understand the lists and dictionaries. And the program that requires the database is expecting a .py file.

Comment: that's not a json content.

Comment: I made the file with this code: `with open("test.py", "r") as file:
   \n data = file.readlines()

\n with open('database.py', 'w') as outfile:
\n  json.dump(data, outfile)`
Where test.py is just `mylist = ("CSDL","ETF","STF")`

Comment: @Cole When generated in this way, your JSON contents are a single list consisting of strings, each string a line from the original `test.py`. It's valid JSON, but the element `mylist` is opaque (inaccessible) to you because it's really just a string -- a sequence of characters `'m'`, `'y'`, `'l'`, `'i'`, ... `'F'`, `'"'`, `')'`. You'll need to do some parsing of the contents in `test.py` before you save it to JSON to be able to do what you're hoping to do.

Comment: See my new answer and please explain _why_ you would encode the contents of a python file as a JSON Array of Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (hopefully) final rewrite of this answer to get you to the module you're looking for.  What it *sounds like* is that you're after some form of data persistence.  Depending on the scope of your project a database or JSON file may be appropriate, but you may also be able to work with a `shelve`.

```
import shelve
myData = shelve.open('mydata.slf') # Can be any name here
if 'Key 1' not in myData:
  myData['Key 1'] = dict(key1 = 'val1')
print(myData['Key 1'])
myData.close()
```

The best way to think of this object is as a Persistent Dictionary.  It uses pickle behind the scenes, but provides a more familiar grammar.  In other files you can reopen the same `shelve` and the keys will be available.  [Full Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html).

Comment: Sorry about being vague, i am just learning about all of this stuff today and clearly do not understand it all. I have a database file that needs to be .py whose lists and dictionaries are being referenced. In another program, i want to be able to bring in this database.py file and modify (add/subtract items from) the lists/dictionaries and then overwrite the main database file. It seems that a JSON format is the best way to do it. Although pickle was also suggested to me.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me.